# Get Cocoapods to automatically set the correct swift version

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

For some reason when I performed a `pod update` the swift version changed on all my pods and am now receiving various build errors. Is there a way for Cocoapods to select the correct swift version for each pod to prevent the build errors?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `pod update` is to update to current versions. If you don’t want to update, but rather just want to install the versions specified in you `Podfile.lock`, you would just do `pod install`.

But now that it’s already updated, you have two options: Either revert your `Podfile.lock` file to its previous version (the preferred approach) or manually specify the desired versions in your `Podfile` with the `~>` syntax. Then you can do `pod install`.